# Azure Boards: retrieve all Work Items from a certain board of a given team

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops, workitem, azure-boards

I'm writing an application that retrieves the teams of a given Azure project. After this is done, the user can select the teams he wants in order to see the corresponding work items from Azure Boards. Until now I have managed to use the API and retrieve the boards of the selected Teams, using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/boards/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) resource which returns the id, url and name of the boards, but I cannot seem to find a URL to get the work items associated with those boards.

I understand that an alternative to this is to use WIQL, but I cannot find in the documentation how to do this. The closest thing I've managed to do is a POST request on the `https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=5.1` URL with the body: `{"query": "Select [System.Id], [System.Title], [System.State] From WorkItems Where [System.WorkItemType] = 'Feature'"}` but I end up getting all the work items instead of the ones from the project and team I specify in the URL.

What I want to use is a query like: `Select [System.Id], [System.Title], [System.State] From WorkItems Where [System.Team] = 'Team1' AND [System.Board] = 'Features'`. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding:

```
AND [System.AreaPath] UNDER 'ProjectName\Team'
```

Note: `ProjectName\Team` will work so long as your area path naming is set up to give each team its own area directly under the project. Go to Project Settings -> Teams -> Select your team -> Iterations and Area Paths -> Areas, then look at the Area assigned to the team. That's what you should use in your WIQL.

To get the Area Path for your team by API,  use

```
https://dev.azure.com/{orgName}/{projectName}/{teamName}/_apis/work/teamsettings/teamfieldvalues?api-version=6.0"
```

The result of that (at least for me) returned a `defaultValue` property that contained the Area Path for the team.

Comment: Thank you! I will try doing this, however I cannot access those settings because I intend on using this application for users other than myself. Do you have any idea of an API call that could give me the area of a given team? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Added an API call that should get you the area path for your team.

Comment: Thanks a lot! One last question, how should I go about adding the board constraint in the WHERE clause? I know that I can filter by WorkItemType, but for instance one of the users has 19 WorkItemTypes (got this using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20item%20types/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) resource, so there are the 15 default types and 4 custom) but one of its teams has only 3 boards, corresponding to 3 of the aforementioned work item types. What should I do?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking for.

Comment: My bad, just realised that querying only by the area path will retrieve all the work items I need. What I was trying to do was, for instance, if a team has the Features and Stories boards set up, I wanted to only retrieve the work items of type Feature and Story, but I believe this is no longer necessary. I am still a beginner in Azure Boards so I don't know if my reasoning is correct :D